# Wave Broadband service refusal

Tags: legal-terms, legal-research, legal-education, service

and thank you for your time, I have a question in terms of the legality of a dispute between wave and myself.

My grandma is displaying the signs of altzheimers so my girlfriend and myself moved in with her, however she has been forgetting to pay her bills so we took over paying rent, power, garbage etc. My girlfriend works from home, and therefore needs to be able to access the internet, however when we tried to contact Wave about setting up internet, we found out that my grandma had an unpaid bill with them, (that she refuses to square up) so they refuse to provide to this address regardless of the fact it wouldn't be in her name, nor would she be using it. Is this legal? I was under the impression it was illegal to attempt to hold somebody accountable for another's debt.

Answer (score 3):

Wave Broadband is a private company; they can *probably* decide to not provide service to an address that is in arrears or collections. I'm sure there is a clause in their service contract that states they can do that, and there would be local or state laws to support that. Whatever public service commission governs the state may also allow that.

It's possible that Wave is breaking the law by denying service to a whole address, but doubtful. You can check with the state level public service commission.

Comment: Thank you, I'll be looking into a different provider.